# Proving an inequality using basic facts

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Basic Facts:

Let $a,b,c\in\Bbb R$, then

1. If $a<b$ and $c>0$ then $ac< bc$
2. $a^2\ge0\land a^2=0$ iff $a=0$
3. If $a\ge0$, there exists a unique number $\sqrt a$ whose square is $a$
4. If $a<b$ and $b<c$ then $a<c$

My new attempt:

[image: New attempt]

Could someone tell me if my approach in proving the inequality is correct? If not could you please tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a circular argument, you start from the inequality you want to prove, that's wrong. A correct way is much simpler, too:

Comment: Your very first line is false.  if $\frac {\sqrt x}{x+ 1} > 1/2$ then $\frac 12*\frac {\sqrt x}{x+ 1} > \frac 12* \frac 12 = \frac 14$  And we have no way of knowing at this point if $\frac {\sqrt x}{x+ 1} > 1/2$ or $\frac {\sqrt x}{x+ 1} \le 1/2$

Comment: @OP Please do not vandalize your question.

Comment: To be honest, with just those four facts I don't think it can be proven.  In your text was any information given *defining* ">"?  I suspect there are more we can be using.  Example: Have we been told that for all non-zero x that either x < 0 or x > 0. (That'd be a "fact") or that $a < b \iff b-a > 0$?

Comment: $ We\ proved\ that\ if\ 0<\ a<b\ then\ a^2<b^2\ and\ \sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b} $

Comment: But you havent proved or provided any reason for $a < b \implies a+x < b+x$.  That's ... nescessary.

Comment: $ If\ I\ state\ that\ a\ +x\ <b\ +x\ then\ can\ I\ say\ that\ 2\sqrt{x}\le x+1 $

Comment: You can say whatever you like.  I'm just trying to understand how this material has been presented to you as a problem as it really doesn't make sense on its own.  There are usually two ways of doing this.  Either it's given as an axiom $a < b \implies a+ x < b+x$ or is is given to you as an axiom that all numbers are either <, = , > 0 and $a < b \iff 0 < b-a$.  If you have one of those then yes $x -2\sqrt{x} + 1 \ge \iff x + 1 \ge 2 \sqrt{x}$.  But without it, you'll never get anywhere.  I think by now you are doing everything correctly, but I can't believe these 4 facts are all we have.

Answer (score 2):

Using (2) applied to $a=\sqrt{x}-1$ gives, using that, by (3), $\sqrt{x}^2=x>0$,

$$0\leq (\sqrt{x}-1)^2=x-2\sqrt x+1$$ which immediately yields the desired, by means of (1).

Comment: Hi, I tried to prove again using your idea. Could you please have a look?

Comment: How would that lead to the result.  We can't claim $0 \le x - 2\sqrt{x} + 1 \implies 2\sqrt{x}\le x + 1$ with only the facts given.

Answer (score 0):

Using your argument, we can prove:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\le\frac14$$

As we have:

$$\frac14\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\le\frac1{16}$$

and

$$\frac{x}{(x+1)^2}\le\frac14\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}$$

so

$$\frac{x}{(x+1)^2}\le\frac1{16}$$

and

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\le\frac14$$

But this isn't true - take $x=1$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is circular. You start with the conclusion and then arrive at that conclusion.

Here is a valid proof:
$0 \leq (x-1)^2$ by fact 2
$\implies 0 \leq \frac{1}{4}(x-1)^2$
$\implies 0 \leq \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}$
$\implies x \leq \frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}$
$\implies x \leq \frac{1}{4}(x+1)^2$
$\implies \frac{x}{(x+1)^2} \leq \frac{1}{4}$
$\implies \frac{\sqrt x}{x+1} \leq \frac{1}{2}$